# Can one swap fixed ip address of tomcat in Jelastic environments?

Tags: jelastic

We have 3 environments running in Jelastic in a standard OTAP way: test, acceptation, production.

Every tomcat in that environment has a fixed ip adress.

What I would like to do is swap the addresses of production and acceptation so that after a succesfull test on accaptation we swap acc and prod.

Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: I just posted an update to my answer that may help you further, if you're still looking for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, the way to achieve this is using a proxy (NGINX load balancer), and manually adjusting which tomcat it points to according to your needs.

The load balancer will have your public IP and that way it will not change.

Unfortunately you cannot currently create an environment with only the load balancer and nothing else, so you will need to put it within any environment that is running all the time.

UPDATE:

It's now possible to move a public IP between nodes (and between environments), using the Jelastic API or CLI tool. The command is `~/jelastic/environment/control/swapextips` (the necessary params are stated in the help output).

The API method is also in the same location if you prefer to use your own API client instead.

See http://blog.layershift.com/php-7-jelastic-paas/#portable-ip for more details.